# Tagging system files

Tags: macos

I noticed that system files and folders cannot be tagged using the UI in Finder and I am wondering whether there is a workaround – Terminal based or otherwise.

There are a number of system files I'd like easy access to and tags would serve that purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing [what @Lauri Ranta proposes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106109/any-way-to-set-add-tags-on-a-file-with-applescript-under-mavericks) : doing this with `xattr`

Using `xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo "$(xattr -px com.apple.FinderInfo 'file1')" "file2"`
you can copy the tag from file 1 to file 2. 
Since `/System/` is not writable for users, you just going to need to use `sudo`.

Edit:  To see the tagged files, you'll need a Finder with root access. 
You can get it as using :

`killall Finder &&udo /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder`

**/!\ But Warning**. A Finder with Root access is very dangerous and you could easily destroy your system.

Edit2: With the Root Finder you can directly change the tag without using the command line. But Again, root Finder is baaaad.

Comment: Okay … tagging works, technically. Any idea how I can get the file to show up in the "tagged as" selection now?

Comment: Probably because you're not the owner of this file. Run a Finder with root access (which is baaaaaad).

Comment: I concur, not a good idea. Even though you technically  provided a working solution I'll leave this question unanswered for a little while longer in the hopes of getting a workaround for the related issue that doesn't involve root and/or messing with the files in question more than strictly appropriate.